# TypeError converting a Pandas Dataframe to Spark Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Did my research, but didn't find anything on this. I want to convert a simple `pandas.DataFrame` to a spark dataframe, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3]})
sc_sql.createDataFrame(df, schema=df.columns.tolist())
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

I tried something even simpler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
sc_sql.createDataFrame(df)
```

And I get:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Any help? Do manually need to specify a schema or so?

`sc_sql` is a `pyspark.sql.SQLContext`, I am in a jupyter notebook on python 3.4 and spark 1.6.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code works fine, there is no error.

Comment: It doesn't for me, with or without schema...

Comment: which spark version are you using?

Comment: I'm on Spark 1.6.1

Comment: What version of Pandas do you use?

Comment: Pandas is `0.18.1`

Comment: ok, with the newest updated version to Pandas (`0.18.1`) it now seems to work! apparently I had an older version that was the problem. thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

It's related to your spark version, latest update of spark makes type inference more intelligent. You could have fixed this by adding the schema like this :

```
mySchema = StructType([ StructField("col1", StringType(), True), StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True)])
sc_sql.createDataFrame(df,schema=mySchema)
```